# Pandas - take N previous values and creating matrix out of Series

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have this Series:

```
S = pd.Series([1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34])
```

I want to convert it to a matrix, where each row will contains the last `N` (let's say: 5) values.

So the output should be:

```
[[NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN],
 [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN, 1],
 [NaN,NaN,NaN, 1,  1],
 [NaN,NaN, 1,  1,  2],
 [NaN, 1,  1,  2,  3],
 [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  5],
 [ 1,  2,  3,  5,  8],
 [ 2,  3,  5,  8,  13],
 [ 3,  5,  8,  13, 21]]
```

Iv'e tried using `rolling` but didn't figure out exactly how to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shift` with `concat`

```
out = pd.concat([S.shift(x) for x in range(1,6)[::-1]],1)
Out[124]: 
     0    1    2     3     4
0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   1.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0   1.0
3  NaN  NaN  1.0   1.0   2.0
4  NaN  1.0  1.0   2.0   3.0
5  1.0  1.0  2.0   3.0   5.0
6  1.0  2.0  3.0   5.0   8.0
7  2.0  3.0  5.0   8.0  13.0
8  3.0  5.0  8.0  13.0  21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of `numpy` and `pandas`

```
n = 5
a = [np.nan] + S.tolist()
a_out = np.flip(pd.DataFrame([a[:-i][::-1] for i in range(1,n+1)]).to_numpy(), 
                (0,1)).T
    
Out[464]:
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan,  1.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  1.,  1.],
       [nan, nan,  1.,  1.,  2.],
       [nan,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  8.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  5.,  8., 13.],
       [ 3.,  5.,  8., 13., 21.]])
```

Or purely `python` and `numpy`

```
n = 5
a = S.tolist()
a_out = np.flip([a[:-i][::-1] + [np.nan]*i for i in range(1,n+1)], (0,1)).T

Out[476]:
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan,  1.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  1.,  1.],
       [nan, nan,  1.,  1.,  2.],
       [nan,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  8.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  5.,  8., 13.],
       [ 3.,  5.,  8., 13., 21.]])
```